# Same command on multiple servers

Tags: ssh, command

I'm just wondering if there is any fellow sysadmin with the need to execute one command on multiple servers.
If so, what technique are you using?

I have grown tired to ssh-ing to 3-5 servers and executing the same thing over and over again, so I'm thinking to make my life easier.
Also, I think I should create keys so I don't have to enter passwords anymore (though I'm using root). After 2 years of doing this, I kind of developed a laziness.

I googled it up, I know about cssh, pssh, tentakel (this one seems cool), and the more pro-genre - Puppet (of which I just heard of, didn't invest the time to read the docs).

BTW, I'm using XP+putty, so if there is any putty-cool-thingy available, that's welcome too. If not, I can always ssh to one server and from there start my rest-of-the-servers-conquest  :) *evil*

Hit me up. Thanks.

Comment: Ever heard of a batch file?

Comment: that's not quite a great idea.

Comment: What are you executing? How do you know it worked or had the expected result on all the servers without actually going through them one-by-one or introducing an actual management system? Things sometimes sound a bit complex for a reason (though more often for no good reason) ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at:
`clusterssh`

Comment: I'm on xp so I can't use clusterssh

Comment: I suppose it can be done via Cygwin.

Comment: i just searched it and it doesn't seem to be a way. i found puttycm which is for $indows, but it needs many improvements. clusterssh would had been great, indeed.

Comment: from http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=FAQ#Working_Platforms :  "It should work on
any POSIX compliant UNIX style OS, i.e. cygwin"

also google search gives -> http://jon.limedaley.com/plog/post/installing-clusterssh-on-cygwin

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: I've had troubles installing clusterssh on Windows using Cygwin, and the Perl that was available to Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a Ruby person then [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) is worth considering.  If you're keen on the idea of Puppet then cfengine and bcfg2 are also worth taking a look at.

I'm really liking Capistrano for regular tasks, though I'm not sure I'm using it very well and I'd probably benefit from some training.  For more one-off tasks I'd recommend clusterssh.

Comment: capistrano looks kind of complex :(

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:

http://www.millardsoftware.com/puttycs

It is a wrapper around PuTTy that performs a similar function to Cluster SSH.

Comment: I'm using puttycs myself. To help in opening multiple windows at once, I also found http://www.ntsend.freeserve.co.uk/puttymenu.html

Answer (score 2):

dssh or pssh may provide you with what you need.

Comment: Just tried pssh, it's even available by default as a package in Ubuntu  (although the command is called parallel-ssh there). Works perfectly!

Comment: Happy to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh keys setup and installed and want something simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
SRVLST="server1 server2"

for SRV in $SRVLST
do
    echo Logging into root\@$SRV
    ssh root@$SRV "$1"
done
```

However if you really want to controll things properly you should look at a utility such as [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/)

Comment: cssh and dsh do this better

Comment: there are likely many many better ways to do this; it's a simple option nothing more. The preference would be to implement a system to actually control them along the lines of Puppet as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Actually I do have a script in bash that does this for my apache-cluster:  
   
read answ  
com=\`ssh web2 "$answ"`  
echo "$com"  

  
but I want to try something more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to execute the same commands on a set of servers, then I would suggest clusterssh: I use it routinely and it works very well.

Comment: don't i need x-server for cluster ssh?

Comment: Yes, clusterssh needs an X server, I use it on Windows boxes with Cygwin's X-Server.

Comment: @sebastianopilla how many servers do you open in one session? do you have more than 10? I have two LCDs but I cannot resize the cygwin window, so I'm basically stuck to one LCD's size (17", 1280x1024) and if I want to open more sessions I cannot cram them up in there. Can you resize?

Comment: @woot, the maximum I've done is 6, on my setup (26" main screen, 17" secondary screen) it was quite usable. I've just tried it again, and I was able to freely resize all of windows; if it doesn't work for you then there might be some issue with your Cygwin/X setup, or with clusterssh's .csshrc file.

Comment: @sebastianopilla I was referring to the cygwin window itself, not the other windows contained in it. So the one that it is displayed in your Taskbar, can you resize that one?

Comment: @woot, I have one Cygwin/X window that I can resize freely where I type the clusterssh command: this command then opens one independent window for each terminal, which all are freely resizable again. Try lauching Cygwin/X with the "-multiwindow" parameter and see if it improves the situation.